# How do I schedule a comment on Reddit?

Tags: comments, reddit

How can I schedule a Reddit comment, similar to how you can schedule email and tweet sending on [Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/9214606?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) and Twitter,<sup>[[1]](https://business.twitter.com/en/help/campaign-editing-and-optimization/scheduled-tweets.html)[[2]](https://twittimer.com/)</sup> respectively?

According to multiple sources,<sup>[[1]](https://www.quora.com/How-can-we-schedule-a-Reddit-post?share=1) [[2]](https://www.reddit.com/r/MarketingAutomation/comments/16vhz66/schedule_posts_on_reddit/) [[3]](https://laterforreddit.com/) [[4]](https://www.delayforreddit.com/can-you-schedule-a-post-on-reddit)</sup> you can schedule Reddit posts to send at a later time. Can you do it with comments too? If so, then how?

Answer (score 2):

It is not currently possible to schedule posts or comments on Reddit in advance. Reddit does not have a built-in feature for scheduling posts or comments, and there are no third-party tools that offer this functionality.

If you want to post or comment on Reddit at a later date, you will need to do so manually by visiting the site and creating the post or comment at the desired time.

Answer (score 2):

Tl;Dr: It's not possible using built-in features only.

---

Reddit regular users are not able to schedule posts using the built-in features. The [Reddit User Help Center](https://www.reddithelp.com/hc/en-us) doesn't include any mention of "scheduling posts" (tried several word variants). The article [How do I post on Reddit?](https://www.reddithelp.com/hc/en-us/articles/360060422572-How-do-I-post-on-Reddit-) doesn't mention how to schedule a post. There is not help article about how to add a comment.

Reddit moderators are able to schedule posts. For details see [Scheduled and recurring posts](https://mods.reddithelp.com/hc/en-us/articles/360037199532). This help article doesn't mention that comments could be scheduled.

You might use third party apps for Reddit or apps like Zappier, Make.com, etc.

For those with programming skills or interest, an interesting thing to consider is to join the Reddit Developer Platform. See [Coming Soon: Reddit Developer Platform](https://www.redditinc.com/blog/coming-soon-reddit-developer-platform-a-unified-space-for-developers-to-create-and-launch-programs-and-apps-to-run-specifically-on-reddit). On the sign up form for the waiting list you will be asked what do you want to develop. You might mention that you want ot develop an app to schedule comments.

### Related

#### From Software Recommendations

- [Free service for scheduled cross-posting to major social networks](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1044/14228) from 2019.
  This [answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1066/14228) mentions Reddit